# ¿Cómo puedo separar un texto delimitado de una columna en R?

Tags: r, string, rstudio

Tengo un dataframe con una columna compuesta por "Nombre, Titulo. Apellidos"
¿Cómo puedo crearme una nueva columna con sólo el título? Es decir, delimitando por ", " y "."
[image: Así es la columna]

Gracias,

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando `stringr` y un poco de expresiones regulares es bastante sencillo:

```
library(stringr)

str <- c('Braun, Mr. Owen Harris', 'Moran, Mr. James')    
str_match(str, ',\\s(\\w+)')[,2]

[1] "Mr" "Mr"
```

El patrón a buscar `,\\s(\\w+)` es básicamente, buscar un coma, un espacio y capturar la siguiente palabra.

Comment: Hago esto:    `df_new <- df_orig%>%
                         str_match("Name", ',\\s(\\w+)') `  y me da el siguiente error: **Error in str_match(., "Name", ",\\s(\\w+)") : 
  unused argument (",\\s(\\w+)")** Soy muy nuevo en R y la verdad que ando un poco perdido.

Comment: dontcare, el problema es no es del `regex`, que funciona, es que para crear una nueva columna usando `%>%` es necesario usar `mutante(). `df %>% mutate(titulo = str_extract(str, "(?<=\\,)(.*)(?=\\.)"))` También funciona con el regex de la respuesta de Patricio

Comment: ay, muchas gracias, con el `mutate`ya me funciona tú código @mpaladino pero el de @Patricio Moracho me sigue sin funcionar. Y tengo un problema con el tuyo, hay un caso: Rothschild, Mrs. Martin (Elizabeth L. Barrett) que selecciona hasta el último punto "Mrs. Martin (Elizabeth L" en vez de hasta el primer punto. ¿Cómo se puede cambiar para que extraiga hasta el primer punto? Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: `df %>% mutate(titulo = str_extract(str, '(?<=\\, )(\\w+)'))` Captura la palabra siguiente a una como y un espacio, al usar  lookbehind `(?=)` no captura la coma y el espacio. La solución de Patrcio funciona con `df %>% mutate(titulo = str_match(str, ',\\s(\\w+)')[ ,2]) `. En este caso en lugar de usar lookbehind para no capturar la coma se hace un subset posterior a partir de `str_match()` Es muy parecido.